# How to clone a virtual Windows disk to a physical disk on VMware - I changed ownership of my host's Windows disk by accident

Tags: windows, vmware, clone, clonezilla, ownership

I did not pay attention, to the following VMware warning, when mounting the drive as writable.

[image: Vmware Warning - VMWare Workstation 12.5.5]

Here's what I was trying to do:

I was planning to mount a 16 GB VMDK file with Windows installed on it on my laptop which runs Windows, and then copy the content of it (both local disk and system reserved - all partitions) on a 16 GB USB thumb drive (created with two partitions to replicate the VMDK) and try to see if I can boot Windows from the 16 GB USB thumb drive on a MacBook Pro.

Since I wanted to copy the drive to an external USB I had to change ownership from `TrustedInstaller` or `SYSTEM` to my user because **Windows wasn't allowing me to copy anything**.  I right-clicked the mounted drive, and changed recursive ownership of the files and folders on the drive, and gave myself Full Control.

BUT, Windows is using Symlinks, when I thought it was only changing ownership of the USB disk, it actually changed ownership of my laptop's SSD  which Windows OS runs on it.

I didn't realize what I had done up until the copy began.  80 GB was getting copied from a 16 GB VMware drive.

I googled and changed the ownership of the mounted drive back to `NT Service\TrustedInstaller` and removed my user from there.  I don't have any system restore nor any backups.  I ran, `sfc /scannow`, but it did not find any issues.

So on a Windows Primary partition there are a lot of shortcuts or symlinks, when I was changing the ownership of the entire mounted VMDK drive, because of those symlinks, it started changing ownerships on the laptop's internal Windows partition as well. It's because the symlinks point to a C:\ drive, and when I mount the VMDK, although the VMDK is assigned a different drive letter than C, the symlinks will still point to C:\ so it causes this behavior. For example there are a lot of symlinks in `C:\Users\username\Links`.

---

UPDATE after a year and half:

I really didn't like what happened to my computer at that time, so I reinstalled windows.

I'm still searching for a way to install a Windows 10 copy on a USB stick using VMWare, Windows does not support installing on an external drive natively.

I wanted to try CloneZilla, but since I already learnt my lesson, first I searched to see what are the precautions I need to take before attaching a physical usb disk to the VM and clone the VMDK (with Windows installed on) to the USB stick.

And I found this: https://pubs.vmware.com/ws65_ace25/ws_user/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ws_user&file=hardware_rawdisk.html

> Caution After you add a virtual machine disk by using one or more
>   partitions on a physical disk, never modify the partition tables by
>   running **fdisk** or a similar utility in the guest operating system. If
>   you do so, you must re-create the virtual machine’s physical disk.

fdisk is a partitioning tool, does this mean that I will not be able to clone using CloneZilla? Because it sure has to partition the USB stick, since a Windows install has more than one partitions.

So I tried this nevertheless and somewhat half way through cloning process with CloneZilla I got an error from VMWare:

[image: CloneZilla Error]

I clicked Retry and Continue multiple times, it gave me the same error again and again. When I clicked cancel, it shut down the VM.

I checked disk management and found out that my USB stick has 3 partitions now and an unallocated space.

Is there any fix for this?

Is there any way I can clone my VMDK Windows copy to a physical USB stick?

Comment: What VMWare software are you using exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Hello, VMWare Workstation 12.5.5

Comment: 16 GB or 160 GB. 16 GB isn’t even enough for Windows.

Comment: Yes 16 GB because I was planning to mount the 16 GB VMDK file and then copy the content of it (both local disk and system reserved) on a 16 GB USB thumb drive (created with two partitions to replicate the VMDK) and try to see if I can boot Windows from the 16 GB USB thumb drive on Mac Book Pro.

Comment: Windows does support it with Windows to Go by now. If you can open the disk in your host just do a low level copy on your host (e.g. using `dd`).

Comment: @Seth Hello :) I have read a lot about Windows To Go, I don't think it's a proper V2P (Virtual to Physical) conversion tool. `Windows To Go is no longer being developed. The feature does not support feature updates and therefore does not enable you to stay current. It also requires a specific type of USB that is no longer supported by many OEMs.` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview

Comment: I'll try `dd` and I think I have to partition it myself

Comment: Yes, Windows to Go is not a conversion tool. But it is/was a way to install Windows on a USB thumb drive. Your probably primarily stems from having a vmdk and wanting to turn that into a physical machine. Have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/33858/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-vmware-vmdk-image-file-to-physical-hardisk-drive/297335) fro some more ideas.

Comment: `dd` worked perfectly, I didn't have to format or partition the target disk at all, `dd` does all of that. I should note that installing the Windows 1809 on the VM, just as soon as installation finishes and starts the countdown to restart, I had to turn off them VM, then ran the `dd` on a linux VM, adding the target disk as USB device and the VMDK file.